"Quasi-symplectic" dynamical systems
The specific objects of interest in this question are dynamical systems that satisfy classical "quasi-Hamilton" equations of motion of the form
\begin{align*}
\dot q = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p},\quad \dot p(q) = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q},\quad 
\end{align*}
where $p$ is a function of $q$, so that $p(q(-t))$ or $p(-q(t))$ also formally satisfies the equations of motion with conjugate "momentum" $q$ (i.e. $p(q)$ is an isomorphism of configuration space.)  Clearly the above set of equations can only be true for a restricted set of Hamiltonians $H$, and over a restricted set of configuration space manifolds. Heuristically, they are Hamiltonian dynamical systems whose phase space can be "compressed" efficiently to the configuration space alone. Have equations/systems of this sort been studied extensively?
One (possibly contrived) example of a system whose orbits individually satisfy a system of equations is a simple two-dimensional harmonic oscillator (with "conventional" Hamiltonian $K = \frac{\vec p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}\vec q\cdot W \vec q$): generically, orbits are ellipses, with two orthogonal principle axes that can be interpreted as $q$ and $p$ for a "two-dimensional" pseudo-operator, and where $p(q)$ is a 90 degree rotation (in a direction that determines the "quasi-Hamiltonian" $H$) and rescaling along the principal axes. The equations of motion of a two-dimensional oscillator are symmetric under time-reversal, and hence both $q(-t)$ and $p(t)$ are solutions. Note that "mass" that appears in the "quasi-Hamiltonian" $H(q,p)$ associated with a particular family of orbits of this oscillator will depend on the "aspect ratio" of the family of orbits, and that while all families of orbits result in quasi-Hamiltonians of oscillator form (which are dynamically similar to each other), their masses will generally differ.
Are there other more interesting examples of systems that satisfy these equations (e.g. families of curves, with associated "quasi-Hamiltonians"?)
